# Golang Paho MQTT over Websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, mqtt, aws-iot, paho

Hey I was trying to connect to AWS IoT Core via Golang Paho MQTT client. I tried the normal MQTT connection which was working without problems. Next I wanted to try the connection via MQTT over Websocket but could not find anything relating that in the Paho.Mqtt docs. How do I make the Websocket connection? I could post my code from my normal MQTT connection if necessary.
Edit, here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

type Message struct {
    message string
}

/*var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("TOPIC: %s\n", msg.Topic())
    fmt.Printf("MSG: %s\n", msg.Payload())
}*/

func main() {
    cer, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cd5a04e9fd9a094326c9ee0cdc1e1f7b2e3510a9e106968683d333a2a4344ca7-certificate.pem.crt",
        "./cd5a04e9fd9a094326c9ee0cdc1e1f7b2e3510a9e106968683d333a2a4344ca7-private.pem.key")
    check(err)

    cid := "ClientID"

    // AutoReconnect option is true by default
    // CleanSession option is true by default
    // KeepAlive option is 30 seconds by default
    connOpts := MQTT.NewClientOptions() // This line is different, we use the constructor function instead of creating the instance ourselves.
    connOpts.SetClientID(cid)
    connOpts.SetMaxReconnectInterval(1 * time.Second)
    connOpts.SetTLSConfig(&tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cer}})

    host := "a2to6mbspmaw82-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    port := 443

    brokerURL := fmt.Sprintf("wss://%s:%d", host, port)
    connOpts.AddBroker(brokerURL)

    mqttClient := MQTT.NewClient(connOpts)
    if token := mqttClient.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }

    var message = "message from lap"

    for message != "bye" {
        token := mqttClient.Publish("some_topic", 0, false, message)
        token.Wait()
        message = "bye"
    }
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Eclipse Paho GoLang [page](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/golang/index.php)

> The type of connection required is specified by the scheme of the
> connection URL set in the ClientOptions struct, for example:
>
> - `tcp://mqtt.eclipseprojects.io:1883` - connect to mqtt.eclipseprojects.io on port 1883 using plain TCP
> - `ws://mqtt.eclipseprojects.io:1883` - connect to mqtt.eclipseprojects.io on port 1883 using WebSockets
> - `tls://mqtt.eclipseprojects.io:8883` - connect to mqtt.eclipseprojects.io on port 8883 using TLS (ssl:// and tcps:// are
>   synonyms for tls://)

The second entry in the list suggests you just pas in the URL with the right schema ( `ws://` or probably `wss://`)

Comment: This is also covered in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#ClientOptions.AddBroker) "The format should be scheme://host:port Where "scheme" is one of "tcp", "ssl", or "ws", "host" is the ip-address (or hostname) and "port" is the port on which the broker is accepting connections. " (I should add `wss` and `unix` to that list). The paho page has not been updated for some time and seems to be missing a link to the docs...

Comment: I saw that there is a Type Websocket in the Paho library, using that is not necessary so I guess? So basically I do the same but I instead of tls prefix I use wss and the other port?

Comment: And one more thing, did anyone already connect to AWS IoT core via MQTT over Websockets and could show some example?

Comment: You only need to set the port if it's not the default (e.g. 80 for `ws://` or 443 for `wss://` )

Comment: I just tried to connect via Websocket, I got an Error: Websocket close  1005(no status)
Added my code on the top

Comment: AWS IoT does not support certificate based authentication for MQTT over WebSockets https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

Comment: Oh I see , is there any example of Go code for Signature v4 or the custom authentication?